# In SQL, I need to generate a ranking (1st, 2nd, 3rd) column, getting stuck on "ties"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a query that calculates points based on multiple criteria, and then orders the result set based on those points.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
         dbo.afunctionthatcalculates(Something, Something) AS Points1
        ,dbo.anotherone(Something, Something) AS Points2
        ,dbo.anotherone(Something, Something) AS Points3
        ,[TotalPoints] = dbo.function(something) + dbo.function(something) 
) AS MyData
ORDER BY MyData.TotalPoints
```

So my first stab at adding placement, rankings.. was this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(MyData.TotalPoints) AS Ranking, * FROM (
    SELECT same as above
) AS MyData
ORDER BY MyData.TotalPoints
```

This adds the Rankings column, but doesn't work when the points are tied.

```
Rank  |  TotalPoints
--------------------
1        100
2        90
3        90
4        80
```

Should be:

```
Rank  |  TotalPoints
--------------------
1        100
2         90
2         90
3         80
```

Not really sure about how to resolve this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `DENSE_RANK()` function which takes the ties into account, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx

Comment: OH MY GOSH! Was it really this simple? Coolest answer and fix... too easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

DENSE_RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER()